# SharePoint unique values from lookup

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list with a lookup column that is getting "Created" dates from another list, but I only want the unique date values. Is there a way to get this data or to create a calculated column with unique values?

Answer (score 1):

A lookup field actually links to a single item, the display value is more a "human readable" value for the link to the items ID value.

You may also get some mileage from a normal text or even date field and using jQuery and [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) on the edit and new forms in order to provide changes to the form for the user. This avoids doing a code level customisation for the site that a [Custom Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg132914.aspx) would require.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box I dont think. My best bet is to create a Custom Field type that extends lookup with the functionality you are after.